# Get all characters of string except the last 2 in bash

Tags: string, bash, substring

I would like to know how I can print the string I have but without having the last two characters in bash.
for example:

```
str = "hello.c"
```

And then print only `hello`

Thank for answers.

Comment: Do you really mean except the last 2, or except the extension? What if it's `hello.cpp`, do you want `hello` or `hello.c`?

Comment: Either case is explicitly covered in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use [bash-builtin string manipulation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```bash
str="hello.c"
echo "${str%.c}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v7ikyFYpIzUnJ18vWYkrNTkjX0FJpRooqqqXXKv0/z8A)

#### To quote the documentation:

> `${parameter%word}`
>   `${parameter%%word}`
>
> The *word* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>    expansion. If the pattern matches a trailing portion of the expanded
>    value of *parameter*, then the result of the expansion is the value of
>    *parameter* with the shortest matching pattern (the '`%`' case) or the
>    longest matching pattern (the '`%%`' case) deleted. If *parameter* is '`@`'
>    or '`*`', the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional
>    parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If
>    *parameter* is an array variable subscripted with '`@`' or '`*`', the
>    pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in
>    turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: Quote: `echo "${str%.c}"`. Otherwise, if `IFS=l`, you'd print `he o` as output; or, with the default IFS, if the string had a literal tab you'd change it to a space (a whitespace-surrounded glob would be replaced with a list of names in the current directory, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added that. thanks

Comment: Please also consider finding a better reference than the ABS -- half the time we spend in the freenode #bash channel is helping people unlearn bad habits they picked up there. [The bash-hackers' wiki reference on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) is a good source. Another is [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100). And of course there's the [official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a real noob in shell script.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I changed it now, citing the official documentation instead of what I had before.